# I am receiving errors trying to record both audio and video using libcamera-vid and libav on a PiZeroW running no GUI and headless

Tags: video, recording, alsa

I had video working fine, but when I add audio recording I run into lots of trouble.  The first set of problems deal with finding format combinations that work.  The second set ig giving me trouble finding the identifier stream for the audio in card.

I have first included my source code followed by an error log when running.

```
while True:  
now=datetime.now() 
date_time=now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
 output_filename=CarID+date_time+"%04d"+"h.264" print("Output
 Filename:",output_filename) recording_args=" -t20000 -n --codec libav
 --libav-format mp4 --libav-audio --audio-codec acc --inline --audio-source alsa --audio-device default --audio-bitrate 32768 --profile baseline --width 1280 --height 720 --framerate 30" record_command="libcamera-vid" + recording_args + " -o " +
 output_filename print("record command:",record_command)
 os.system(record_command)
 ## DON'T FORGET TO RESTORE SEGMENT AND TO RESTORE LOOP FOREVER
```

...and here is the error log:

> Script started on 2023-06-25 19:04:04-04:00 [TERM="linux" TTY="/dev/tty2" COLUMNS="240" LINES="67"]
> [?2004h[01;32mdbbarron@raspberrypimini[00m:[01;34m~/VideoRecorder $[00m exitsudo nano AudioTest2.pyls[Ksudo nano AudioTest2.py[1Plibcamera-vid --format[1Pformat[1Paudio-libav[4P--libav-audio 1,0[Kformat[Klibcamera-vid --helppython AudioTest2.py
> [?2004l
> Date-Time: 20230625190414
> Output Filename: MBM09720230625190414%04dh.264
> record command: libcamera-vid -t20000 -n --codec libav --libav-format mp4 --libav-audio --audio-codec acc --inline --audio-source alsa --audio-device default --audio-bitrate 32768 --profile baseline --width 1280 --height 720 --framerate 30 -o MBM09720230625190414%04dh.264
> [2:45:32.271842698] [1115] [1;32m INFO [1;37mCamera [1;34mcamera_manager.cpp:299 [0mlibcamera v0.0.4+22-923f5d70
> [2:45:32.683455525] [1116] [1;32m INFO [1;37mRPI [1;34mraspberrypi.cpp:1476 [0mRegistered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
> [2:45:35.760388329] [1116] [1;31mERROR [1;37mV4L2 [1;34mv4l2_videodevice.cpp:1047 [0;32m/dev/video13[15:out]: [0mUnable to set format: Invalid argument
> [2:45:38.800291508] [1116] [1;31mERROR [1;37mV4L2 [1;34mv4l2_videodevice.cpp:1047 [0;32m/dev/video13[15:out]: [0mUnable to set format: Invalid argument
> [2:45:41.840291685] [1116] [1;31mERROR [1;37mV4L2 [1;34mv4l2_videodevice.cpp:1047 [0;32m/dev/video13[15:out]: [0mUnable to set format: Invalid argument
> Mode selection:
> SRGGB10_CSI2P 1536x864 - Score: 3100
> SRGGB10_CSI2P 2304x1296 - Score: 3400
> SRGGB10_CSI2P 4608x2592 - Score: 4300
> [2:45:41.848585601] [1115] [1;32m INFO [1;37mCamera [1;34mcamera.cpp:1028 [0mconfiguring streams: (0) 1280x720-YUV420 (1) 1536x864-SBGGR10_CSI2P
> [2:45:41.871997364] [1116] [1;32m INFO [1;37mRPI [1;34mraspberrypi.cpp:851 [0mSensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a - Selected sensor format: 1536x864-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1536x864-pBAA
> [2:45:44.880322861] [1116] [1;31mERROR [1;37mV4L2 [1;34mv4l2_videodevice.cpp:1047 [0;32m/dev/video13[15:out]: [0mUnable to set format: Invalid argument
> ERROR: *** failed to configure streams ***
> [?2004h[01;32mdbbarron@raspberrypimini[00m:[01;34m~/VideoRecorder $[00m [?2004l
>
> exit
>
> Script done on 2023-06-25 19:04:33-04:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="0"]